# Get Grand Total from gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to loop through each variable in the gridview (which is bound with database) to get the grand total from gridview?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price">
<ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="UnitPriceField" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductPrice")%>'>             
          </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach looping the `GridViewRows` with Linq:

```
double total = gridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
          .Sum(r => double.Parse(((Label)r.FindControl("UnitPriceField")).Text));
```

However, note that it's always better to calculate such things in the database instead of the GUI.

Comment: close to what I needed but very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) can do what you need, there are tons of examples:

[GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Displaying Summary Data in the Footer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972833.aspx)